# To insert a new item into a ListBox and placed it as the first entry and get it selected

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, listbox

Currently, I have the following:

1. A `SqlDataSource` called `SqlDataSourceVenue` (it is configure to retrieve data from a table inside a SQL Server 2008)
2. A ListBox called `ListBoxVenue` (which is also configure to use `SqlDataSourceVenue` by using the `Choose Data Source` as shown in the Illustration A)
3. A code (Code A) that will insert a item into the ListBox under the Action Properties (Illustration B) `DataBound` option.

**Illustration A**

[image]

**Code A**

```
    protected void BoundedItemsVenue(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ListBoxVenue.Items.Add("{BLANK}");

    }
```

**Illustration B**

[image]

The problem currently is that the new Item `{BLANK}` will always be placed as the last entry of the ListBox.

Is it possible to make my new Item to appear or placed as the first entry inside my Listbox and also have that new Item be selected?

Comment: It a bit lazy question. You shoud've documented on ListBox control  and collections before.

Comment: Actually previous I tried using the `ListBoxVenue.Items.Add(new ListItem("{BLANK}","0"));` but it did not placed it as first item. Never thought that the correct way should be using `Insert` rather than `Add`. Sign.

Comment: Only documentation can give you all existing tools that you may need to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ListBoxVenue.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("","{BLANK}"));
ListBoxVenue.SelectedIndex = 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with

```
ListBoxVenue.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("","{BLANK}"));
```